# Error with div animate on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Good evening, friends.
Here is the site - http://p-karnaukhov.ru/ .
On scroll this block http://joxi.ru/L21dE4XUQRkqmX must move to left to screen off.
On scroll back it must come back to it's starting position.
I already did scroll to left, but  don't come back correctly. 
If we scroll more or less - block stay to wrong position.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            jQuery('.flex-caption').animate({left: "-=20"}, 100);
        } else {
            jQuery('.flex-caption').animate({left: "+=20"}, 100);
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
});
```

Help me please resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be alone in this but I don't like jQuery. A sales pitch to make things easier often becomes burdensome code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveDiv(scrollamt) 
{
 var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
 var rightMargin = myDiv.style.marginRight;
 myDiv.style.marginRight = rightMargin+scrollamt;
}
</script>

<body onScroll="moveDiv(this.scrollTop);">
```